# Best practices for teamcity and dotnet pack

Tags: .net, .net-core, teamcity

I have a .sln with bunch of projects. Some of them are netstandard, some are net framework, some are unit tests (also with mix and match between core & framework).

I'm trying to figure best way for Teamcity to understand which csproj should be packed, which should not. Now we just use `dotnet pack` at solution level. This leads to packing of XXX.Tests — I don't want that.

Our build engineer suggest passing a list of projects to pack from Teamcity and store this as patrt of Teamcity configuration. I don't like that and want this information to be stored in source code.

What's the best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IsPackable` property of a .csproj. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties), `IsPackable` is:

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the project can be packed. The default value is true.

So it's a simple matter of adding the following to your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You don't have to put this in its *own* `PropertyGroup` element - you can simply add it to an existing one if you'd prefer.